# Living Trust in Hebrew

Tags: hebrew, ketubah, estates-inheritance

For the purpose of a kethubah the groom is writing that the [living trust](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/living-trust-faq-29036.html) that is in the bride's name shall remain her property. But i don't know how to render "living trust" in Hebrew. Does anyone here know the words or phrase for living trust in Hebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but isn't it this - נכסי צאן ברזל?

Comment: Apparently there is נכסי צאן ברזל and  נכסי צאן ברזל

Comment: right, both of them are living trust so to say, but with different conditions.